# Google Groups API

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

Both a clarification and suggestion question - is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_groups the full Google Groups API page? I've read through it, but haven't been able to decipher if the API would allow me to plug into it from another site and remove/add users as needed from groups. I might just be spoiled from the Google Maps API which has a plethora of examples available, but is this possible? I'll want to interact with both public and private groups. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the page you linked to is for a Google Groups service within Apps Script, Google's cloud scripting solution. There are ways you may be able to utilize Apps Script, but that code must be written in Google's editor, and can't be run from your web page directly.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate you clarifying that.